# How to upgrade wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.4 in odoo using ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-10, openerp-8, qweb

I wanted to print barcode for a product in `odoo10`.
    For this barcode is not printing because in my `ubuntu 14.04`, `16.04`
`wkhtmltopdf` version is `0.12.0`, it is changes to `0.12.2.4` version barcode is print.
    But I have use so many commands to update the version of `wkhtmltopdf`, it is not effected.

Please any one help to update this version..

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade`. This will help you to show if any of the install packages have updation is there or not.

Answer (score 2):

First setup you have to do Uninstall the wkhtmltopdf package:

```
sudo apt-get remove wkhtmltopdf --purge
```

Now Second Step  Install Stable Wkhtmltopdf Version
Navigate to a temporary directory:

cd /tmp

Download the recommended version of wkhtmltopdf for Odoo server. In this example, we use 0.12.1. See the Odoo repository for an up-to-date list of compatible versions:

```
sudo wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Install the package using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

To ensure wkhtmltopdf functions properly, copy the binaries to a location in your executable path:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```

> Note: While wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.2.4 is available in the official
>   Ubuntu 16.04 repository, we don’t advise installing it from there due
>   to the large number of dependencies including: xserver, gstreamer,
>   libcups, wayland, qt5 and many more. There isn’t an official Xenial
>   package from the project page yet, but the Trusty package from Ubuntu
>   14.04 is compatible as of this publication.

===================
You want Unstable version then you can get it from here:

```
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases
```

Comment: Thank u for your response #Patel Sahab..:)

Comment: This uninstallation is not working. After running this command sudo apt-get remove wkhtmltopdf --purge.. I run wkhtmltopdf --version .. I get output.
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)

Comment: The reason it did not uninstall for you is because you did not use apt-get to install the package. Only the packages installed through the package manager can be removed through package manager.